# GitLab non-root self-managed runners fail with "No such file or directory"

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I'm running a GitLab non-root self-managed runners as a daemon

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner-ansible.service
[Unit]
Description=GitLab Runner as ansible
After=syslog.target network.target
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner

[Service]
StartLimitInterval=5
StartLimitBurst=10
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner "run" "--working-directory" "/home/ansible" "--config" "/home/ansible/.gitlab-runner/config.toml" "--service" "gitlab-runner-ansible" "--syslog" "--user" "ansible"

Restart=always
RestartSec=120

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and I registered a runner

```
$ gitlab-runner list
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=1206452 revision=de7731dd version=12.1.0
Listing configured runners                          ConfigFile=/home/ansible/.gitlab-runner/config.toml
orc2_production                                     Executor=shell Token=secret-token URL=https://my.gitlab.com/
```

The runner get a task and fail to process with the following `journalctl` log

```
Apr 19 17:34:28 svko-ilcm03 su[1205544]: (to ansible) root on none
Apr 19 17:34:28 svko-ilcm03 su[1205544]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user ansible(uid=1001) by (uid=0)
Apr 19 17:34:28 svko-ilcm03 su[1205544]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user ansible
Apr 19 17:34:28 svko-ilcm03 gitlab-runner-ansible[1204663]: WARNING: Job failed: exit status 1                  duration=209.648477ms job=82078 project=2705 runner=Psx6ypMS
Apr 19 17:34:28 svko-ilcm03 gitlab-runner[1204663]: WARNING: Job failed: exit status 1                  duration=209.648477ms job=82078 project=2705 runner=Psx6ypMS
Apr 19 17:34:28 svko-ilcm03 gitlab-runner-ansible[1204663]: ERROR: Failed to process runner                     builds=0 error=exit status 1 executor=shell runner=Psx6ypMS
Apr 19 17:34:28 svko-ilcm03 gitlab-runner[1204663]: ERROR: Failed to process runner                     builds=0 error=exit status 1 executor=shell runner=Psx6ypMS
```

In the GitLab web interface, I find

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.1.0 (de7731dd)
  on orc2_production Psx6ypMS
Using Shell executor... 00:00
Running on svko-ilcm03... 00:00
bash: line 106: cd: /home/ansible/builds/Psx6ypMS/0/ilcm/orc2: No such file or directory 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Why is the GitLab runner not cloning my project?

Comment: Reported a long time ago at https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-runner-as-non-root-does-not-clone-repo/21935

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Alex M in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3849#note_134574796, remove `/home/ansible/.bash_logout` resolved the problem.

A deep explanation of the problem is provided by colinhogben at https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-runner-as-non-root-does-not-clone-repo/21935/6.